# Minimum characters to enter - regex non character issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I use this regex in combination with asp:RequiredFieldValidator to force user to enter minimum 7 characters:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]{7,}
```

But when user enter non letter **@, ., -** etc then this doesn't work.
How to enable to enter all characters and minimum 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `Regex` expression:

```
^.{7,}$
```

Answer (score 5):

Your regex only accept numbers and letters. the "." matches any single character except a newline character.

So the new regex would be ".{7,}" or "\S{7,}".

\S matches any nonwhite space character (so no spaces,newlines, tabulations, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

The correct expression for minimum 7 character-entries is 
`.{7,}`
"." stands for any character (white space inclusive)
To solve the whitespace problem, you can use `\S{7,}` (CAPITAL S!)

If you like to have a nice tool to help you get along with regex, i can recommend [Regex Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/)
It's freeware and very easy to use  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Regex isn't meant to solve everything.

You could use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

```
  <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ControlToValidate="Text1"
       Display="Static"
       ErrorMessage="Must be at least 7 chars!"
       OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
       runat="server"/>
```

You can handle the `ServerValidate` event and check the length:

```
void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = args.Value.Length >= 7;
}
```

Comment: But I need this in form of validator.

Comment: With `MaxLength`, it doesn't allow you to type more than 7 chars, so there's not need for validation.

Comment: I added an example with CustomValidator as another option.

Comment: @jrummell He requires the opposite, some kind of `MinLength` which actually doesn't exist.

Comment: @jrummell Use `>= 7`, I guess.